# How to count number of integer digits in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My task is to write a program that calculates how many digits a number contains. You may assume that number has no more than six digits.

I did this

```
`enter code here`

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int a, counter=0;;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>a;

    while (a!=0) {
        a=a/10;
        counter++;
    }

    cout<<"The number "<<a<<" has "<<counter<<" digits."<<endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I put condition that there are max 6 digits, and why is "a" outputting as a 0?

Comment: ``floor( log10F((float)number))``

Comment: You may also want to add special case for `0` - it has one digit.

Comment: Sorry - it really is: ``ceil(log10F((float)number))``

Comment: @BitTickler [both are wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a95f62a11a458f5)

Comment: How many digits does "0000001" contain?

Comment: lol yeah, right. So here the last try (with demo): ``[1;9;10;99;100;999;1000;9999;10000;99999;100000;999999;1000000;99999999]
|> List.map (fun x -> x, int (floor(log(float x)/log(10.)) + 1.))`` yields: ``[(1, 1); (9, 1); (10, 2); (99, 2); (100, 3); (999, 3); (1000, 3); (9999, 4);
   (10000, 5); (99999, 5); (100000, 6); (999999, 6); (1000000, 6);
   (99999999, 8)]`` errm with (1000000, 6) I think I failed again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few changes...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int a, counter=0;;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>a;

    int workNumber = a;

    while (workNumber != 0) {
        workNumber = workNumber / 10;
        counter++;
    }

    if(a == 0)
        counter = 1; // zero has one digit, too

    if(counter > 6)
        cout << "The number has too many digits. This sophisticated program is limited to six digits, we are inconsolable.";
    else
        cout<<"The number "<<a<<" has "<<counter<<" digits."<<endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You run the loop until `a==0` so of course it will be 0 after the loop.

Take a copy of `a` and either modify the copy, or print out the copy. Don't expect to modify `a` and then still have the original value.

You don't need a condition that it has max 6 digits. You were told you *may assume* no more than 6 digits. That doesn't mean you can't write a solution that works for more than 6, or that you must enforce no more than 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int digits = floor(log10(n)) + 1;

if (digits > 6) {
    // do something
}

std::cout << "The number " << n << " has " << digits << " digits.\n";
```

Comment: funny, how this works with floats, but not with doubles. See my comments to question above :) Btw. For singles, it also goes wrong for 8 9s (99999999). see: http://ideone.com/NdTXAu